# Android Realm Bad Transaction Log

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm to persist data in my Android app and just got this crash with Realm. The circumstances: I am using RealmResults in a Fragment. There is a trigger to switch to another set of data, but it has not yet been saved to Realm. So I read the new from a file, save it to Realm then re-run my query to overwrite the prior RealmResults in the same Fragment.

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Bad transaction log in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 210
at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeRefresh(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.refresh(SharedRealm.java:281)
at io.realm.HandlerController.realmChanged(HandlerController.java:450)
at io.realm.HandlerController.handleMessage(HandlerController.java:121)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I found this response (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3702) in response to the same crash but I do not understand the concept of the response:

> Bad transaction log could indicate problems with the file somehow.
>   I see you are using Sync. Note that you cannot open an old Realm in Sync mode. You need to move all data there. Trying to open an old Realm as syncable will result in the error you are seeing.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What does "open an old Realm in Sync mode" mean? Do I need to close Realm in my Fragment and get a new Realm instance before overwriting my RealmResults? This is highly intermittent, so it's not a matter of simply trying it once and seeing if it fixes the problem.

UPDATE: Finally fixed by not opening any Realm instance in MainActivity. So I have to check for schema migration in one of its ViewPager fragments. (FWIW the crash occurs when beginTransaction() is called in an AsyncTask of a Fragment, though I can see from my error logging that the AsyncTask continues to work after the crash). I think the problem is related to using Realm in an AsyncTask of a Fragment.  The reason I think this is because I have another Activity with a ViewPager, but no problems with Realm, I assume because those ViewPager fragments do not utilize Realm + AsyncTask.

Although I no longer believe my crash is related to attempted schema migration, as requested, here is how I do that:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("my_realm.realm")
            .schemaVersion(MyConstants.MY_REALM_SCHEMA_VERSION)
            .modules(new MyRealmModule())
            .build();
    try {
        Realm.migrateRealm(config, new MigrationMyRealm());
        System.out.println("debug tag, migrated realm");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("debug tag, there is no realm to migrate");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // realm is already open -- cannot migrate it
        System.out.println("debug tag, could not migrate realm because it is open");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `findAll()` or `findAllAsync()`?

Comment: I am using findAll(). The problem appears to be related to RealmMigration. I indiscrimately attempt to migrate my schema whenever I open the app, but if I turn that off the problem goes away. Since it doesn't seem like there is a way to query the oldVersion of a Realm Schema, I guess I have to keep track of that and attempt to migrate only when the schema has actually been updated.

Comment: That sounds like a bug that will be fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3800 you should file a new issue on their Github

Comment: Can you by chance share the previous realm configuration, and how you tried to migrate previously?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce see my updated answer, though I no longer thing that's the issue. I think it is a combination of Activity-Realm + Fragment-AsyncTask-Realm.